# How to make my discord.js chat bot reply to a word in a sentence

Tags: discord.js, bots

I’m trying to set up a chat reply bot for helping admin a game discord server. I have a list of words for it to reply to and can get him reply to them no problem. The problem I’m having is that one of the words is ESP so when someone was to type the word response it picks up the word esp in the word response and replies when I don’t want him to. Another example is the work hack. When someone types hacksaw ridge in chat he replies to that to. I want it to just look for the word esp along with a few other cheating terms and not look for it in the middle of a longer word.

```
let cheater = ["cheating", "cheater", "aim_bot", 'esp', "hack"]

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return false;

  if (cheater.some(w => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(w))) {
      message.reply('if you think someone is cheating report it here <#976517390701563955>');
  }

})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of ways to solve it is very simple in fact, if you want your bot to react only to full words, you can use:

```js
if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes(` ${your_variable} `)) {
  // your code
}
```

instead of what you have in your code

Comment: Thank you, I’m still very new and am really just trying to learn and understand as I go. What would I enter in the {you_variables} section to make it search from a list of words rather than just a single word?

Comment: @timmieTurner ```if(cheater.some(w => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(` ${w} `)))```

Comment: So I ended up trying this at it wouldn’t respond to me unless I typed (' ${w} '))) nothing from the list was being picked up at all.



`client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
   if (message.author.bot) return;
   const cheater = ["cheating", "cheater", "aim_bot", 'esp', "hack"]

   if (cheater.some(w => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(' ${w} '))) {
      message.reply("if you think someone is cheating report it here <#976517390701563955>")
   }
})`

Comment: @timmieTurner because you need to use `` instead of ''

Comment: perfect that's a woops on my part. when i was testing just only typing esp not in a sentence it wasn't responding, didn't realise it needed to have the white spaces either side also. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for an `Array.prototype.some()` to get the `message` in your `array`. To accomplish this.

```
client.on('messageCreate', async(message) => {
   if (message.author.bot) return false;
   let messages = ["cheating", "cheater", "aim_bot", 'esp', "hack"]

   if(messages.some(element => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(element))) {
      message.reply("if you think someone is cheating report it here <#976517390701563955>")
   }
})
```

Comment: So that worked for picking up the words in my list. But say if someone was to also type the word response which is not in my list of words but has the 3 letters “esp” in the middle of it. It will also send back the message.reply. Any way to get it to check for white spaces around the words in my list? So it only picks up the word in the list and not when one of the words in in another longer word?

Comment: It will trigger the `event` because you are using `.includes`

Comment: `hacking` will trigger the `event`, `hacked` also, `hacking` because you are using `.includes` even it is a longer word or a sentence

Comment: Is the away around for making it not search for a word contained inside of another word while still picking it up in a sentence at all? To it do to an exact match or check for white spaces.